# How to calculate proper object movement?

Tags: java, multithreading, path-finding

I need some help with homework. We've got a "Thread Show" in class tomorrow, and mine is almost done. I've got USS Enterprise flying behind a Klingon spaceship, shooting photons whilst Captain Kirk shouts out orders. Its working pretty fine, but one thing I don't like is that I can't control very well the trajectory of the photon. Since the way I'm emulating the movement is by += the x and y's, it seems to be going in the same direction, no matter where the Klingon ship is located. (I did manage to get it to shoot left, right, up or down, just not exactly towards the ship. Ideally I want it to shoot to the location the ship was last at when I created the PhotonThread. (its not supposed to always hit it. Just a linear trajectory..) )

Here is part of my code, I'd really appreciate any help or pointers on how to fix that.

```
 /**
 * 
 */
package actualProgram;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;

/**
 * @author Stryk3r
 *
 */
public class MainApp extends Thread {

    static boolean deflector, lockEnemy, phasersFire, photonEffect, redAlert, redAlertEffect = false;
    static int EnterpriseX;
    static int EnterpriseY;
    static int EnterpriseSpeed;
    static AudioClip sound;
    static int KlingonX;
    static int KlingonY;
    static int KlingonSpeed;
    static int KlingonDirectionX;
    static int KlingonDirectionY;
    static String KlingonImage = "images/FirstEditKlingon.png";

    static String soundPath;


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        new EnterpriseThread(0,0, "images/FirstEditNCC.png").start();

        try {
            sleep(800);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        new KlingonThread(400,400, "images/FirstEditKlingon.png").start();

        try {
            sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        new SoundThread().start();


        while (true) {
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if (distanceToKlingon(EnterpriseX, EnterpriseY, MainApp.KlingonX, MainApp.KlingonY)  <200.) {


                try {
                    sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new PhotonThread(EnterpriseX+75, EnterpriseY+30,"images/Photon.png").start();
                new PhotonSound().start();



            }
            try {
                sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }


    private static double distanceToKlingon(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    }

}
```

And here's part of the PhotonThread code:

```
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        int direccionX = 1, direccionY =1;
//      Random random = new Random();

        while(true) {



            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int klingonX = MainApp.KlingonX;
            int klingonY = MainApp.KlingonY;

            if (this.x < klingonX)
                direccionX = 1;
            else if (this.x > klingonX)
                direccionX = -1;

            if (this.y < klingonY)
                direccionY = 1;
            else if (this.y > klingonY)
                direccionY = -1;

//          this.x = this.pendienteX;
//          this.y = this.pendienteY;


            while (true) {

                this.x += 10 * direccionX;//la constante es la velocidad
                this.y += 10 * direccionY;//la constante es la velocidad

                try {
                    sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (this.x > Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width
                        || this.y > Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height || this.x < 0 || this.y <0) {
                    //bolitaJframe.hide();
                    bolitaJframe.dispose();
//                  this.stop();

                }

                if (distanceToKlingon(this.x, this.y, klingonX, klingonY)< 60.0) {
                    //MainApp.KlingonImage = "images/roja.png";
                    bolitaJframe.setVisible(false);

                    try {
                        sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("ship destroyed");
                    bolitaJframe.dispose();


                }

                bolitaJframe.setLocation(this.x, this.y);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in your photon code do you read klingonX and klingonY?

Comment: @arynaq KlingonThread sends continually its location to MainApp and stores it in that variable. And I use that same variable in the photon thread to determine which direction to use it.

Comment: @arynaq specifically:  int klingonX = MainApp.KlingonX;
            int klingonY = MainApp.KlingonY;

Right after the first while( true ) loop..

Answer (score 0):

When you set your `directionX` and `directionY` variables based on the position of the other ship, there is no variation in the "amount" you're moving in each direction. You should be looking into some trigonometry to solve that problem for you.

I don't want to do your homework for you, but that should set you on the right path. Think about how you would break down a straight line between two points into components that correspond to your x and y axes.

**EDIT**

A straight line between two points is partially defined by its slope, so that will definitely matter. Consider that your firing ship is the origin of your coordinate system, and the ship being fired upon is a point your line from the origin intersects. If that ship is at (3, 4) (for example), the line has a slope of 4/3. If you wanted to move directly to the ship, you would have `directionX = 3` and `directionY = 4`

This is not exactly what you want however, because you'd rather be moving at a constant rate than jump around. If you want your overall speed to be 1, you would need `C*(directionX**2 + directionY**2) == 1` where C is some constant. `C*(9 + 16) == 1 -> C == 1/25`. So you'd want to scale your directions by 1/25. That would look like `directionX *= C; directionY *= C` Keep in mind you will be recalculating `C` each time you move.

This is not the most robust or technical approach, but it avoids using trig functions or identities other than the Pythagorean Theorem. I would definitely suggest looking into that side of things more when you have the time.

Comment: yes that's where I'm trying to get at. Wouldn't have to deal with the slope, since its a straight line? I just can't wrap it around my head how to do that in terms or += x and y..

Comment: thanks a million...sorry for the late response. Your information helped a lot. I got it finished, and will be presenting tomorrow. THANKS! If you're curious as to how it actually worked irl, here's a link: http://tinyurl.com/kkjz9sz

Again, thanks a lot!